# Set Theory : Proof regarding multiple intersections of sets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Our set is defined as $$A_n :=\left]0,\tfrac{1}{n}\right[$$Where *n*∈$N$. What is? $$\bigcap_{n+1}^\infty A_n$$

Solution : Let’s examine $A_1,\,A_2,\,A_3$:

$$A_1:=\left]0,1\right[$$ $$A_2:=\left]0,\tfrac{1}{2}\right[$$$$A_3:=\left]0,\tfrac{1}{3}\right[$$
It's clear that $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$. Let's define this multiple intersection through an index set $I$:$$\bigcap_{i\in I}^\infty A_i:=\{x∣\forall i\in I:x\in A_{i+1}\to x\in A_n\}, I\subseteq \Bbb N,$$

where $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: The intersection is empty.

Comment: What does the notation $]a,b[$ mean?

Comment: @Vsolvep The same thing as $(a,\,b)$.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen it before. I would have guessed it meant the complement of $(a,b)$

Comment: @Vsotvep This notation is quite common. Note that $(a,b)$ can be an open interval, a point in the plane or an inner product!. To avoid confusions some people use $]a,b[$ for an open interval.

Comment: @Vsotvep See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3386038) recent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on @KaviRamaMurthy's comment: for any $x>0$, there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ with $\frac{1}{n}<x$, so $x\notin A_n$. Hence $\bigcap_nA_n=\emptyset$.

Comment: Is this the same as saying "The only common element across all these sets is the empty set"?

Comment: @juhani no, the empty set is not an element of any of the intervals. What it says is that there is *no* common element across all the sets.

Comment: @juhani No, it's saying their common elements are the elements of the empty set, i.e. none at all.

Comment: I'm still confused. Looking at these sets, we could say we are constantly taking a smaller and smaller interval on the reals. Doesn't that mean there is always at least some element which is common across all these sets, i.e " the smallest possible interval is the common element"

Comment: @juhani $\bigcup_{n=1}^kA_n$ is nonempty for any **finite** $k$, but $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is empty.